# Google OpenID - how to use checkid_immediate in javascript?

Tags: javascript, authentication, openid, google-openid

With **openid.mode=checkid_setup** I can open a popup window and if the user is not logged in he will enter his credentials. But if he is already logged in (browser cookie), then the popup will appear and close right away.

Before opening the popup I want to be able to check if the user is already logged in, and if so, get his credentials. I think it should be done with **openid.mode=checkid_immediate**  but I can't figure out how to do it.

It will be great if someone could provide some javascript code to achieve that.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have an onCheckImmediate method that you call on document ready.  The callback for the method should be something like onOpenIdResponse and then you would switch based on the openid.mode response parameters.

```
switch (params['openid.mode']) {
  case 'setup_needed':
  //popup window
  break;
  default: 
    throw 'unknown response';
}
```

Old post, but I might be able to help if you still have any questions.